# How to set correct coordinates for UIImageView to UINavigationController using CGRect?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview, uinavigationbar, frame, cgrectmake

```
imgView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 360, 44)];
[imgView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = imgView1;
```

My problem here is that Image on NavigationBar has some blabnk space at left side corner and its looking bad. So i wanna make the Image displayed on whole Navigation Bar and also if any buttons on Navigation Bar then image should come backgroud.